# Automatic login to a website on windows 7/Chrome via batch file

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch file. I have case select. if user types 26 it will open link 1 chrome.
if user types 27 it will open link 2 in chrome.

But I still can't figure out, how can I make batch login automatically into website with username and password.

I looked for such a script on the google but didn't find anything useful. I know a bit of C++, unix,(also some html and java script) I don't know if it can be done on windows machine using these languages but even if it could be done I think it would be difficult compared to VB or C## or some other high level languages.

I learned how to open multiple sites using basic windows batch commands enclosed in a bat file like:

```
start chrome.exe http://yahoo.com
start chrome.exe http://www.google.tv
```

But still I can't figure out how would actually a click on the bat file would help me to login to the sites also without even typing the username and password.

Do I need to start learning VB(visual basic),dot net, or windows batch programming to do this.is this so dificult.. Please help.

Comment: Have your login page set a token in cookies upon first login. Have your login script look for that token and and authenticate accordingly.

Comment: Unless you're trying to authenticate with windows user credentials, say via an LDAP integration, I would just use a token in a cookie with a long life. It won't matter then what browser you use or your batch file calls. You login script can handle that. This way you can also revoke security tokens as needed and security/access is more centralized and manageable.

Comment: Thanks for hint guys, I am new to cookies and token can you please provide me with some link or guide where I can read more and proceed from there. Thanks

Comment: The approach I suggested assumes you have access to the login script/functions. This this correct?

Comment: No, I just wrote batch code for user(mom and dad) to type in (channel number) and it will open tv stream link in web browser, if it doesn't need login (if it is already logged in) it will automatically full screen the stream via autohotkey script which I also wrote.

Comment: I don't own that website, I just bought paid service from them, but I am trying to make it easy for user(mom and dad) to skip login.

Comment: Ahhh... just have their browsers save their passwords OR google "window macro recorders" and try a few see if they can repeat the login process reliably.

Comment: Ya, that's what I been doing, instead I am using AutoHotKey Scripts, to make it login automatically but, it is becoming more and more nasty. I was wondering for a better way.

Comment: How can I edit the cookie it created, I saw that it will expire in like 2 or 3 hours of login, how can I edit that cookie and make it not edit able again?

Comment: @Mowgli You can't. The cookies suggestion was based on the assumption that you were the author of the website being logged into.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
call WshShell.Run("http://www.gmail.com", 1, false) 'This will open your default browser

WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys "username"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "password"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit()
```

The code opens your browser, waits for the page to load, and then enters the username and password assuming that the cursor is in the right input box (for example, in **Gmail**, it will be on the **username** input box). Else you have to navigate to the right input box by using **TAB**.

If you are against writing the password in the script file, save it on you browser and use the appropriate SendKeys method for logging in.

Answer (score -2):

i tried above script for my website, but only able to see login page not able to put user name and password, need help

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off

set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //C:JScript "%~F0"
START iexplore.exe "www.gmail.com"
timeout /t 5
%SendKey% "USERNAME{TAB}"
%SendKey% "PASSWORD{Continue}"

goto :EOF


@end
// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0))
```