# Any kind of script to log in to WIFI every 90 minutes

Tags: authentication, vbscript, automation, wifi

I am not looking for a hack. I have wifi at home but I am disconnected every 90 minutes and have to press enter to get back in. I have been mucking about to try and write something that will silently open a window, wait for it to load, press {enter} and then close the window. 
Ideally I would leave it on a loop to run every 90 minutes, but just using windows scheduler would be fine.

Here is my failed attempt so far (.VBS)

```
    Dim oIE

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

oIE.Visible = 1 ' Usually Hidden

oIE.Navigate "http://www.autohotkey.com"' anysite will work as if I'm logged out I will be automatically redirected to login

Do While (oIE.Busy)
Wscript.Sleep (10)
Loop

ObjShell.SendKeys "{enter}"

Do While (oIE.Busy)
Wscript.Sleep (10)
Loop

ObjShell.sendkeys "^W"

Wscript.Sleep (5400000)
```

All this does is open new pages with out the delay. 
I've seen a few more complicated version that I have tried but nothing is working. 
I would really appreciate any help, any format is fine as long as it does the job.

Comment: The logic of this script rely on some constant conditions: 1) your browser remember your username/password for this site and this input fields are already filled with correct data, and 2) "submit" button is on focus. If any of those conditions is not met, you'll need to add extra code (not just Enter).

Comment: The problem with send keys is that you should have the windows where you want to send keys to be active or else it will send the keys to the current active window for e.g., the browser while I'm typing this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one code you can try.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
call WshShell.Run("http://www.gmail.com", 1, false) 'This will open your default browser

WScript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "username"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "password"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
WScript.Quit()
```

Try this. It worked [Automatic login to a website on windows 7/Chrome via batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204623/automatic-login-to-a-website-on-windows-7-chrome-via-batch-file/14476249)

You just have to wait while this runs. The browser which it opens should be **active**, then the send keys will type the username, password, enter and then close the window.