# Batch file to open url with credentials

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, curl, http-authentication

I have a Windows 10 and a Windows 7 machine on which I want to open an https website with a batch file. The batch file must contain the credentials (password, username) and a value for the Domain field. The Domain field is a drop down field in the website with values such as 'XYZ'.
I would like to deposit a certain value here.
The aim is for the user to be automatically logged in to the website by double-clicking on the batch file.

How do I write the username, the password and the domain in the batch file correctly?

I started with this, the internet explorer is opening but nothing is happening.

```
@ECHO OFF
start iexplore
curl -u username:password https://mywebsite.com
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403376/automatically-open-a-browser-and-login-to-a-site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically open a browser and login to a site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403376/automatically-open-a-browser-and-login-to-a-site)

Comment: You can try to refer the answer in this link and try to develop your code with the help of that to solve your issue. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403376/automatically-open-a-browser-and-login-to-a-site