# Create a .bat file to open a program/link on the site?

Tags: html, batch-file, automation

I have a website that I have to visit daily and select an application on that webpage. I have creates the .bat file to open the webpage at start up however how can I take it one step further and automatically start the application on the webpage?

Comment: I believe it will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782734/open-a-url-without-using-a-browser-from-a-batch-file

Comment: ... or this it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403376/automatically-open-a-browser-and-login-to-a-site

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have the .bat file below to open the webpage. 

I have the following in the /bat file that currently opens the webpage. 

@echo off

start iexplore myapps.logisticshealth.com/RDWeb/Pages/en-US/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fRDWeb%2fPages%2f
Start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Mitel\"Unified Communicator Advanced 7.3"\UCA

Once the webpage is opened I have to open one of the App pictured below: 
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZrol.png

Answer (score 1):

You can not make a batch file click on a link on a website. the best way to do this is to copy the link on the website and put it in the start command.
`start link.com`

Comment: I have created a .bat file with that part that opens the webpage. i would like to go one step further and open/click one of the applications on the webpage to start it.

Comment: Hmm This may be possible with some C++ code or VBS macro control

Comment: I see what you want though just some experiments will probably give us the answer.