# Pass variables from VBS to Javascript/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, vbscript

How can I pass messages from a VBS file to a GUI created in Node Webkit (Javascript).

For example, status updates etc.

If in my HTML GUI I had a div called output, can I within the VBS communicate a string update to the HTML GUI?

Example uses:

I use the below VBS to check if an update is present:

```
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/XXXXXXXXX/version.txt", False
oXMLHTTP.Send
remoteVer = oXMLHTTP.responseText

'** If there is an update then download the new file.
If oXMLHTTP.responseText > localVer then

wscript.echo "An update is found, downloading..."
```

So at this point I would like the message, an update is found, downloading, to be displayed on the HTML GUI. I can run aspects of VBScript using cases/switches, but I need a method to communicate to the GUI itself from the VBScript.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, maybe I can use a HTA file as a bridge, I wanted the options of HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript for my GUI (Node-Webkit gives me this) but I like being able to write in VBScript, which I can't directly do in Webkit as it's Chromium based. Any ideas?

Comment: Or write with VBScript to a txt file somewhere and have some form of Javascript or Ajax live polling the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic login to a website on windows 7/Chrome via batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204623/automatic-login-to-a-website-on-windows-7-chrome-via-batch-file)